# How do I efficiently copy an entire queue to a vector/an array in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, queue

How do I efficiently copy an entire queue to a vector/an array in C++?

say I have a std::queue and at some point I want to copy it to a vector/an array and then sort it.

Thanks for everyone's answers.

What I really want to do is to create a window with a fix length and at some point i need to copy all the elements inside this window and sort them. the window is moving and there are new data coming in through another interface so i want to use queue. is there any better implementations?

Comment: `std::vector(myQueue.begin(), myQueue.end());` not good enough?

Comment: By 'efficiently', do you mean in terms of algorithmic complexity or terseness of code?

Comment: @Borgleader: `std::queue` does not have iterators.

Comment: @Borgleader not if the queue is an `std::queue`

Comment: Is your queue an `std::queue`? If so, you have to push the front and pop element by element. There is an awful hack using inheritance though...

Comment: @juanchopanza I assumed `std::deque`

Comment: yea my queue is an std::queue

Comment: @Borgleader: std::queue has begin and end?

Comment: You can use a std::deque instead to get all the same functionality and iteration

Comment: @user2565858 (on your update) depends on the data type, the size of the ring, and what speeds you need. For small, low latiency, POD type structures, a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) would work, but it is ugly. If you want something that looks fine and doesn't change your code all that much, just use a deque with Borgleader's first response.

Comment: @Borgleader, you wrote the I can use `myQueue.end()`. This function is exist?

Comment: @Rat No I misread and assumed deque, as stated in previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> What I really want to do is to create a window with a fix length and at some point i need to copy all the elements inside this window and sort them. the window is moving and there are new data coming in through another interface so i want to use queue.

I suggest to take a step back, and reconsider whether you really want to use a `queue`. I suppose you want it because you

1. want to expose a minimal interface to the other component which adds data to the queue.
2. efficient addition/removal of elements at the front/back (to implement the 'fixed width window' concept)
3. an efficient way to access the data visible in the window sorted

Unfortunately, `std::queue` isn't very suitable for (3). Hence, I'd suggest to look for something which addresses (2) and (3), and then consider writing a wrapper of some sort (maybe a plain function which just adds an element to the queue will do?) to implement (1).

For instance, I'd consider using a plain [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/). It can add/remove elements from the beginning/end of the queue in constant time. It's also very easy to get a sorted view on the window, e.g. if copying the elements of the queue is cheap you could use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) like:

```
std::vector<Elem> sortedView( queue.begin(), queue.end() );
std::sort( sortedView.begin(), sortedView.end() );
```

...you could of course also do something more clever by not copying the data but rather creating a `vector` of iterators into the queue, or by using a different sorting algorithm like [`partial_sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to keep a sorted queue, take a look at [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access std::queue elements is using a combination of `front`, `back`, `push`, `pop` since `std::queue` has no iterators. (In order to be able to use iterators, you should use the underlying container (e.g. std::deque) directly, instead of std::queue.

Since you want to make a copy (presumably leaving the elements in the queue as they were), you can push elements back into the queue after you pop them.

Also, since you know the size of the queue, you can use `vector::reserve` to prevent expensive memory reallocations triggered by `vector::push_back`.
So

```
std::vector<int> V;
std::queue<int> Q;
V.reserve(Q.size());
for(size_t numPos = 0; numPops < Q.size(); ++numPops) {
  V.push_back(Q.front());
  Q.pop();
  Q.push(V.back());
}
std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
```

Comment: If you're going to push the elements back onto the queue like that, it will never be empty, and so your loop will never terminate.  Use a for loop counting up to `Q.size()` instead.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley  Crap. Initially I had just the `pop()`, I added the pushing back as an afterthought. Should have tested ...

Comment: Your `numPops` is declared twice; I guess if you wanted to be really pedantic, you'd declare it as `std::queue<int>::size_type` since that's what `Q.size()` returns - or just use `auto` with C++11.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Thanks, fixed. This is why I shouldn't attempt to start the day without coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best option is to **use the right STL data structure from the start**. If you will want to sort the data, a std::queue is **not** the right data structure.

Consider using a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (or perhaps a hash map). Typical implementations of maps actually *build* the map sorted, with lookups being performed in O(ln) time. You can still iterate sequentially through a map too, if you really want to.